# Periodic low ping to and from certain machines on network

Tags: performance, networking, ping

Background:
Me and my co-workers work with a fairly large network, about 600 computers, 100 printers, 40 switches all spread out over town at 20 different locations. The switches are connected via fibre.

Problem:
Last couple of months we have periodically (about 1 time a week) had users call in reporting slow connections. It's the same 10 computers affected each time. Each time the problem last about 4-6 hours. Sometimes it starts in the morning, other times it starts around/after lunch. Both laptops and workstations are affected, but dozens of machines of same models (with same hardware) work fine. Co-workers computers is unaffected even though connected through same switch.

```
Ping table (<-> = both ways):
Affected computers <-> Our servers (80 ms - 250 ms)
Affected computers <-> Other computers (< 1 ms)
Other computers <-> Our Servers (< 1 ms)
```

At all other times, the ping is below 1 ms between any 2 computers on the network. While the problem is ongoing there are hardly any network activity on the affected computers.

What has not worked:
Rebooting Affected computers
Reinstalling the OS on Affected computers.
Switching computers to other ports in the switch.

What sort of works:
Moving the affected computers to a different vlan (causes other problems though, so not a solution).

Any ideas what to look for?